# HBase mapreduce job - Multiple scans - How to set the table of each Scan

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I use HBase 1.2. I would like to run a MapReduce job on HBase using multiple scans. In the API, there is : 
`TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(List<Scan> scans, Class<? extends TableMapper> mapper, Class<?> outputKeyClass, Class<?> outputValueClass, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job job)`.

But how to specify the table of each scan ? I use the code below :

```
List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<>();
for (String firstPart : firstParts) {
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setRowPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(firstPart));
    scan.setCaching(500);
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
    scans.add(scan);
}
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(scans, MyMapper.class, Text.class, Text.class, job);
```

It gives the following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf(TableName.java:436)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.initialize(TableInputFormat.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingInputFormat.getSplits(DelegatingInputFormat.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
```

I think it's normal since the tables on which each scan should be applied are not specified anywhere.

But how to do it ?

I tried to add

```
scan.setAttribute("scan.attributes.table.name", Bytes.toBytes("my_table"));
```

but it gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

#### From docs  https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableInputFormat.html

```
List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<Scan>();

 Scan scan1 = new Scan();
 scan1.setStartRow(firstRow1);
 scan1.setStopRow(lastRow1);
 scan1.setAttribute(Scan.SCAN_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE_NAME, table1);
 scans.add(scan1);

 Scan scan2 = new Scan();
 scan2.setStartRow(firstRow2);
 scan2.setStopRow(lastRow2);
 scan1.setAttribute(Scan.SCAN_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE_NAME, table2);
 scans.add(scan2);

 TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(scans, TableMapper.class, Text.class,
     IntWritable.class, job);
```

#### Your Case :

use `Scan.SCAN_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE_NAME`
since you are not setting table at scan instance level you are getting this NPE...

***please follow this example where you have to set the table name inside your for loop not outside ... then it should work***

```
List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<Scan>();

  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    Scan scan = new Scan();

    scan.addFamily(INPUT_FAMILY);
    scan.setAttribute(Scan.SCAN_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE_NAME, Bytes.toBytes(TABLE_NAME ));

    if (start != null) {
      scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(start));
    }
    if (stop != null) {
      scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(stop));
    }

    scans.add(scan);

    LOG.info("scan before: " + scan);
```